# Hibernate - transaction not started successfully

Tags: java, hibernate

My heavy client made in C# is communicating with Java via web methods. And Java is calling the DB via Hibernate.
I created a web method which allows to retrieve data from a table in C# in order to insert, update or delete in DB.
I've checked and debugged the web method in java and I got back the good data from C#.
I checked my method  step by step and everything seems to be fine except at the end, this line send back an error :

> HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();

There is my method :

```
public BatchSaveResponse setBaseFilter(BatchSaveRequest request) { 
    LOG.info("Executing operation setBaseFilter");
    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOG.debug("Param: request "+ request);
    }
    MessageContext ctx = mc.getMessageContext();
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)ctx.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST);
    
    BatchSaveResponse _return = new BatchSaveResponse();
    ObjectSet insertedObjects = request.getInsertedObjects();
    ObjectKeySet deletedObjects = request.getDeletedObjectIds();
    ObjectSet updatedObjects = request.getUpdatedObjects();
    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOG.debug("SetBaseFilter insertedObjects =  " + insertedObjects);
        LOG.debug("SetBaseFilter deletedObjects =  " + deletedObjects);
        LOG.debug("SetBaseFilter updatedObjects =  " + updatedObjects);
    }
    
    try {
        String remoteUser = getUser(req);
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("SetBaseFilter remoteUser [" + remoteUser + "]");
        }
        HibernateUtil.beginTransaction(remoteUser);
        // INSERTED OBJECTS
        if (insertedObjects != null) {
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("SetBaseFilter::start insert ...");
            }
            // Configure
            ArrayOfCONFIGURE arrayOfCONFIGURE = insertedObjects.getCONFIGURE();
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("SetBaseFilter::insert , arrayOfCONFIGURE = " + arrayOfCONFIGURE);
            }
            if (arrayOfCONFIGURE != null) {
                List<CONFIGURE> elements = arrayOfCONFIGURE.getCONFIGURE();
                if (elements != null && elements.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
                        CONFIGURE currentCONFIGURE = elements.get(i);
                        Configure configure = ConfigureDAOFactory.getDAO().getConfigureFromCONFIGURE(currentCONFIGURE);
                        if (configure != null) {
                            ConfigureDAOFactory.getDAO().createConfigure(configure);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("SetBaseFilter::end insert.");
            }
        }
        // UPDATED OBJECTS
        if (updatedObjects != null) {
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("SetBaseFilter::start update ...");
            }
            // Basefilter
            ArrayOfBASEFILTER arrayOfBASEFILTER = updatedObjects.getBASEFILTER();
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("SetBaseFilter::update , arrayOfBASEFILTER = "+ arrayOfBASEFILTER);
            }
            if (arrayOfBASEFILTER != null) {
                List<BASEFILTER> elements = arrayOfBASEFILTER.getBASEFILTER();
                if (elements != null && elements.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
                        BASEFILTER currentBASEFILTER = elements.get(i);
                        Basefilter basefilter = BasefilterDAOFactory.getDAO().getMinimalBasefilterFromBASEFILTER(currentBASEFILTER);
                        if (basefilter != null) {
                            BasefilterDAOFactory.getDAO().updateBasefilter(basefilter);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("SetBaseFilter end update!");
            }

        }
        // DELETED OBJECTS
        if (deletedObjects != null) {
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("SetBaseFilter::start delete ...");
            }
            // Configure attribute
            ArrayOfCONFIGUREKey arrayOfCONFIGUREKey = deletedObjects
                    .getCONFIGUREKeys();
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("SetBaseFilter::delete , arrayOfCONFIGUREKey = "
                        + arrayOfCONFIGUREKey);
            }
            if (arrayOfCONFIGUREKey != null) {
                List<CONFIGUREKey> elements = arrayOfCONFIGUREKey
                        .getCONFIGUREKey();
                if (elements != null && elements.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
                        CONFIGUREKey currentCONFIGUREKey = elements.get(i);
                        byte[] byteKey = currentCONFIGUREKey.getID();
                        ConfigureDAOFactory.getDAO()
                                .deleteConfigureForId(byteKey);
                    }
                }
            }
            Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("SetBaseFilter::end delete.");
            }
        }
        HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        LOG.error("SetBaseFilter::ERROR : " + e);
        rollbackTransaction();
        String message = getDAOMessage(e);
        LOG.error("SetBaseFilter::ERROR message [" + message
                + "]");
        throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException(
                "SetBaseFilter::ERROR = " + message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("SetBaseFilter::ERROR = " + e);
        rollbackTransaction();
        throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException(
                "SetBaseFilter::ERROR "
                        + e.getCause().getMessage());
    } finally {
        // No matter what happens, close the Session.
        try {
            HibernateUtil.closeSession();
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("SetBaseFilter::session closed!");
            }
        } catch (BaseConnectionServiceException e) {
            LOG.error(e + " : cannot close session !");
        }
    }
    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOG.debug("SetBaseFilter end !");
    }
    return _return;
}
```

The errors :

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: SetBaseFilter::ERROR = Transaction not successfully started.
>
> SetBaseFilter::ERROR : com.***dao.DAOException: Error when rollback transaction.
>
> SetBaseFilter::ERROR message [Transaction not successfully started].

I do not understand why. I start my Hibernation before doing anything, I close it no matter what happens... Thanks !

EDITS:

commitTransaction -

```
public void commitTransaction() throws BaseConnectionServiceException {
    Connection s = (Connection) sessions.get();
    if (s == null) {
        throw new BaseConnectionServiceException("Connection doesn't exist.");
    }
    try {
        s.commit();
        s.setAutoCommit(true);
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw new BaseConnectionServiceException("Error when committing transaction.",
                sqle);
    }
    return;
}
```

beginTransaction -

```
public void beginTransaction(String userName) throws BaseConnectionServiceException {
    Connection s = (Connection) sessions.get();
    if (s == null) {
        createSession(userName);
        s = (Connection) sessions.get();
    }
    try {
        s.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw new BaseConnectionServiceException("Error when begining transaction.",
                sqle);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get ? ... please post it here

Comment: Post your Exception logs please

Comment: Yes my bad, I forget ! I edited my post.

Comment: HibernateUtil.beginTransaction() and  HibernateUtil.commitTransaction() source is also required

Comment: Post code snippet for HIbernateUtils too

Comment: exception tells you that the transaction cannot be started. Please post the beginTransaction() method

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing Hibernate and plain JDBC here.

I advice you use hibernate for your transactions.

Refactor your code to something similar to this:

```
 Session sess = factory.openSession();
 Transaction tx;
 try {
     tx = sess.beginTransaction();
     //do some work
     ...
     tx.commit();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     throw e;
 }
 finally {
     sess.close();
 }
```

Comment: The problem is I'm new on the project, and there are others similar methods which work with the same "pattern" as the one in my post. So I'm not really able to change it... :/

Comment: I doubt that transactions ever worked in the system. Ask some senior dev for explanations

Comment: I've commented the line `HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();` and its work... I'm not sure about what I did but...its work in DB, in java and in C#...What should I think...

Comment: Yes, you guessed it right! There are no transactions in the system ;)

Comment: What you mean by there are no transactions in the system ? I do not understand :/

Comment: the system crashes when you try to commit transaction. Exception tells you that the transaction cannot be started. By commenting the code you're just hiding the problem that transactions aren't working

Comment: I'm agree but the transaction is working fine. My DB is correctly updated and I retrieve the right data. That's akward...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`@Transactional`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#orm-hibernate) in the `beginTransaction` method.

If the method is only a query `readonly = true` is preferable:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void beginTransaction(String userName) throws BaseConnectionServiceException {
```

Comment: IMHO, will not help. Look at how the hibernate session is managed. His Connection is plain jdbc connection

Comment: agree... actually I haven't read the method itself... when this error shows it's always a missing `@Transactional` annotation in my services xD

Comment: that's always happens to me, if everything is configured the right way

Comment: Majestic read @Funtik answer, and if you have problems, use `@Transactional` annotation

Answer (score 0):

It would be worth seeing also code of createSession(). But at the first sight it looks like you use Hibernate to access the database but you use low level JDBC to manage the transaction. This won't work. You have to start transaction on Session.beginTransaction to achieve the goal: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#beginTransaction()

In general I suggest avoiding your own session management and use annotation driven transactions. This will lead to much safer, scalable and you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

The issue came from another method run before my setBaseFilter(). Actually a table is fill thanks to a method called getBasefilter() where there is an HibernateUtil.beginTransaction() but no HibernateUtil.commitTransaction(). So a transaction was open, and when I call setBaseFilter to save the modifications in the tab, I start again an Hibernate beginTransaction without close the previous one.

Thanks all for your help !
Keep going :)